# Parse XML tables with XML::Simple

Tags: xml, perl, hash

I have been using [`XML::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple) for a long time with no problem, but I am facing a situation I had never encountered that I can't solve.

I have an XML file that looks like this

```
$VAR1 = {
          'lvl1' => [
                     {
                       'lvl2' => [
                                 {
                                   'id' => 'myID1',
                                   'type' => 'Type1',
                                 },
                                 {
                                   'id' => 'myId2',
                                   'type' => 'Type2',
                                 }
                               ]
                     }
                   ]
        };
```

I usually use:

```
my $xml = XMLin('filename.xml');

foreach my $element (@{$xml->{lvl1}->{lvl2}) {
    ...
}
```

but it does not work in that case because of the `[]` that are introducing tables inside the hash. I have tried a lot of things to try to go through this but I can't find any way that allows me to access all the element without throwing a `not a hash reference` error.

Comment: To get that result you must have options `ForceArray => 1` and `KeyAttr => 0` or something similar. Is that correct?

Comment: Obligatory: Even XML::Simple says 'don't use XML::Simple'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data structure has a couple of array references thrown in (delimited by [] instead of {} for hash references). Given that you didn't use the ForceArray option, I'm assuming in your real file you have several lvl2 elements under lvl1?

XML::Simple introduces arrays into the data structure whenever there is more than one element of the same name grouped. If you're not sure if you will get one or more elements, you can force the array using the ForceArray option:

```
my $xml = XMLin('filename.xml', ForceArray => ['lvl1']);
```

You can then access the array under lvl2 with the Code choroba gave:

```
for my $element (@{ $xml->{lvl1}[0]{lvl2} }) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the ForceArray tip.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you use [XML::Simple](http://p3rl.org/XML::Simple).

Square brackets introduce arrays (not tables) in Perl. To index arrays, use square brackets:

```
for my $element (@{ $xml->{lvl1}[0]{lvl2} }) {
```